# Can the Jackson parser for JSON support trailling commas?

Tags: java, json, parsing

Jackson is a very flexible JSON parser -- it allows for a lot of options to parse JSON-like strings which do not comply strictly with the JSON spec, but are supported by modern javascript parsers.  For example, it allows comments and using single quotes instead of double quotes.  These options are documented here:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.Feature.html

I'd like to be able to support trailing commas, i.e. `[1,2,3,]` but I don't see this option.  Is it really not supported by Jackson?  It seems like it's not supported, but given how many other options Jackson does support, this surprises me and I'd like confirmation that I'm not just missing it somehow.

Comment: Jackson copes with many forms of input that do not conform to spec, as I stated in the question.

Comment: Wow, I somehow missed that! :)

Answer (score 3):

Not at the moment but there is an issue for it:

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/118

In some cases you can remove the trailing commas using regular expressions before parsing.

Comment: Can you help with that?

Comment: note: the github issue was very recently closed, so hopefully this solves the problem!